# spark DataGrid content goes to invisible when rotate few degrees

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex-spark

I have an android application working on Adobe Air. Simply, I have a Spark DataGrid in a view. When I rotate my devices(tablet or mobile phone) few degrees(4-5), datagrid content goes to **invisible** and

-if I continue to next position(Portrait to Landscape), goes back to visible.

-if I don't continue to next position, doesn't go back to visible.

I have tested this with default properties of spark DataGrid,Item renderer and Skin class, but this problem occured again.Is that may be a bug ?

Appreciated to hear your comments about this issue.

Comment: 1. are you manually rotating ? or this is a default behavior for orientation change ? Why are you using a datagrid in a mobile app? there are known performance issues with it.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu manually mean, think that you are using your device in your hand and by your hand move, rotated. Do you suggest me another component works as viewing rows of datas as datagrid? Thanks

Comment: You should not manually rotate. Check this on automatic orientation http://flexponential.com/2011/11/06/orientation-and-deviceorientation-in-flex-mobile-apps/ . The problem is that rotating "fonts" which are not embedded causes to font not to display. So as a temporary solution for manual rotation use embedded fonts.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu I got the rotation issue and checked the linked page.It's very helpful and I searched about DataGrid and after "dataGrid is slow and bulky even on desktop" comment, decided to use List. Thanks both for your comments.

Comment: Glad I could help. I am also the opinion that using List instead of datagrid is the best decision when it comes to mobile. If you need columns in your list just use a custom renderer and display the content inside an HGroup

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu I already used list with a custom renderer that includes columns before, Thanks so much